# Call to undefined function db_set_active()

Tags: database

I sure I have succeed to use these snippets in previous code, but now I get a "Call to undefined function db_set_active()" error. I don't understand why.

```
public function allUnits() {
  global $dbUtil;

  $list = array();
  $qryStr = "SELECT * FROM unit ORDER BY u_id";

  db_set_active('mpd_pro');
  $rs = db_query($qryStr);

  while ($row = $rs->fetchAssoc()) {
    $list[$row["u_id"]] = $row;
  }

  db_set_active('default');

  return ($list);
}
```

Comment: You may missing some files during the transfer. Try a new Drupal installation.

Comment: But I have the latest core.

Comment: Is this even Drupal code??? How is this function called?

Answer (score 1):

The 2 things that come to mind: your installation is  not bootstrapping properly (improperly configured .htaccess or settings.php) , ***or*** you installation is corrupt.

I would recheck the apache logs, watchdog logs to see if any errors are mentionned, if all fails I would see if the application works with this module disabled, because this function is defined in core on line 2519 in `includes/database/database.inc` and should be available from all your custom module code.

Hope this helps, cheers!

Comment: I sure this is not the installation issue. Because I run code A is succeed, but when the code run to code B, I got this error message. so I don't know why.

Comment: I know you are doubtful, but there cannot be many other reasons. Maybe permission errors, this is why I advised you to check the logs. What os are you using?  find the apache error logs and your watchdog logs and check if anything is in there to clue you in.  This is most certainly a configuration / permission problem,  seeing as how this application is installed and running *on millions of sites*, with db_set_active properly defined. Good-luck friend.

Comment: Unfortunately, I only see "PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function db_set_active() in D:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\mat\classes\UnitUtil.class.php on line 60" in php_error_log...

Answer (score 1):

If that code is called from [hook_exit()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_exit/7), then it can be called when Drupal bootstrap didn't initialize the database system.

In any case, calling [drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_DATABASE)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_bootstrap/7) would assure the database system is initialized.

```
public function allUnits() {
  global $dbUtil;

  $list = array();
  $qryStr = "SELECT * FROM unit ORDER BY u_id";

  drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_DATABASE);
  db_set_active('mpd_pro');
  $rs = db_query($qryStr);

  while ($row = $rs->fetchAssoc()) {
    $list[$row["u_id"]] = $row;
  }

  db_set_active('default');

  return ($list);
}
```

If that doesn't help, then there is effectively something wrong. As stefgosselin said, it could be a configuration problem, or the database.inc file is corrupted, and `db_set_active()` is not found there. If the latter were the case, the site would be problems even when you try accessing the front page; the same is true if your site has problem bootstrapping.